# Sinatra models get loaded before migration is done

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sequel

My cucumber tests which has an env.rb which builds a db from scratch, let the tests fail, cause of relations which doesn't exist at the moment of running the tests.

This is my env.rb, without unnecessary code.

```
require 'pg'
require 'sequel'
DBNAME = 'dbname'
ADMIN_DB = Sequel.connect 'postgres://postgres:@localhost/postgres'

query = ADMIN_DB['SELECT * FROM pg_database WHERE datname = ?', DBNAME]
ADMIN_DB['CREATE DATABASE ?', Sequel.lit(DBNAME)].all if query.count == 0

ENV['DATABASE_TEST'] = "postgres://postgres:@localhost/#{DBNAME}"
DATABASE_TEST = Sequel.connect ENV['DATABASE_TEST']

require_relative '../../app'    

Sequel.extension :migration
Sequel::Migrator.run(DATABASE_TEST, 'db/migrations')
```

My model:

```
class User < Sequel::Model

end
```

And I then use User.new in my tests. 
When I run this, the db and the table both are getting created, but the console still gives me this while running the cukes:

```
  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

I've tried various rearrangements of code in my env, to be sure the migrations are done before my model get's loaded.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you may need to open a new DB connection once the migrations are done.  ORM frameworks need the underlying Database schema in order to function properly; yours is likely failing because you are creating the schema underneath it on the fly.

Comment: @mcfinnigan and in which would you suggest to do that? I tried it in several ways, at the beginning in my model and with environment configs. I still got the same error.